# increment value of a number with a specific timer-value

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, increment

I've tried and looked around but I could not find anything similar.

```
<div> <span>23</span>/ 30 </div>
```

My thought process here is that I want 23 to increment in 1 value every 15th second.

And when it hits 30, it shall stop counting. I have no idea how to make it "stop" counting and how I should approach a problem like this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, note that I do an iteration every second for the demo, but you can lower the rate by doing `setTimeout(count,15000);`.

```js
var wrapper, value, timer;

window.addEventListener('load', startCounter, false);

function startCounter(){
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = startCounter;
    wrapper = document.querySelector('span');
    value = 22;
    count();
}

function count(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    value++;
    wrapper.innerHTML = value;
    if(value < 30){ timer = setTimeout(count,1000); }
}
```

```html
<div> <span>23</span>/ 30 </div>

<button>reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div id="show"></div>

<script>

function timer(){
   var i = 0;
   setInterval(function(){
     i++;
     document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = i;
     if(i > 30){
       i = 0;
     }
   },1000);
}
timer();
</script>
```

//just super simple hope can be inspiration done thank

Answer (score 0):

If a class is added to the span element like so:

```
<div> <span class="counter">23</span>/ 30 </div>
```

Then this javascript code would work:

```
var currentCount = parseInt($('.counter').text());
var increaseCount = function() {
    if (currentCount < 30) { 
        currentCount = currentCount + 1;
        $('.counter').text(currentCount);
        setTimeout(increaseCount, 15000);
    }
    return;
};
setTimeout(increaseCount, 15000);
```

Here is an example with the timer set to a second:
https://jsfiddle.net/aqe43oLa/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var i = 24;
var timer=setInterval( increment, 15000);
function increment(){
if(i<=30)
{
 console.log(i);
 $('.increase').html('').append(i);
 i++;
}
else
{
clearInterval(timer);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><span class="increase">23</span>/ 30 </div>
</body>
</html>
```